# jQuery - .load page via AJAX, callback definition on loaded page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I'm using $('#container').load method to handle loading all the subpages of my site.
Now the deal is, some sub-pages require extra behavior (like form validation etc.)

I'd love them to be self-contained, so - each sub-page has own JS code that handles all the subpage-specific tasks. This however requires some of them to handle "loaded" callback to access the just-loaded DOM nodes.

Any tips on how to achieve it? I tried putting
Copy code

```
<form id="my-form"> .. </form>
<script>
$('#my-form').ready(function() {
    //..
});</script>
```

but it doesn't seem to be triggered when loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured out the problem. It was all about content filtering (second parameter of .load method). 
Now, instead of filtering on JS side, I'm doing it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Since your form/page is loaded, you need to use either of `live` or `delegate` method, for example here is how you could validate your form:

```
$('#my-form').live('submit', function(){
  // your validation code....
});
```

The `live` or `delegate` methods work on any element present now or in *future*.

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/live/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: In jQuery versions lower than 1.4, non-bubbling DOM events like *submit*, *focus* and *blur* cannot be used with *live()*.  As long as you stick to the newer versions, this won't be a problem.

Comment: @Andy E: Yes agreed, we assume latest version of jquery is used, after all it has various fixes especially with event handling.

Comment: the code you provided needs to be put in the "main" code, not the loaded subpage.